# swift get to the server in the background

Tags: swift, background-process

after minimizing/closing(if possible) the application, it is necessary to contact the server every n minutes and, if necessary, display push notifications. With push notifications, the code turned out to be the following

```
func sendNotification(inSeconds seconds: TimeInterval, completion: (Bool) -> ()){

    removeNotification(withIdentifiers: ["inurewd"])
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: seconds)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "title"
    content.body = "body"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from : date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "inurewd", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}

func removeNotification(withIdentifiers identifiers: [String]){
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: identifiers)
```

but I can not understand the work of the application in the background. Can u help me, what method will suit me and how to implement it ?

Comment: Send silent notification to device every N minutes and do what you need in background

Comment: @canister_exister how i can continuously call a function (or call once and make an infinite loop) in the background ? I tried NSTimer - it doesn't work in the background, I tried background fetch, but it worked if I chose "emulate background fetch" in xcode, but it doesn't work on a real device (minimized the application, closed - doesn't work)

Comment: You will not able to work in background more than 3 minutes. Best for you is send silent notification from server side every N minutes in this way you can wake up app and work in background

Comment: https://medium.com/@m.imadali10/ios-silent-push-notifications-84009d57794c

Comment: As @canister_exister says, you can't do that. You can run at most for 3 minutes in the background before you get suspended. You will need to set up a server to send a series of silent push notifications. The system will wake/launch your app when it receives a push and you can handle it then.